# Как узнать разницу между датами с минимальный интревалом в один день?

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, дата, datetime

Есть БД Realm, которая хранит объекты с записями о действиях пользователя. Структура объекта с записью такая: `timestamp` с датой и коллекция действий пользователя. При совершении нового действия нужно взять последний записанный объект из базы и посмотреть, если объект с записями сегодняшнего дня уже существует, то записать в него, если нет (последнее действие производилось вчера), то создать новый объект и записывать уже действия в него. Вопрос, как сравнить даты с интервалом в день? Есть `Date.before()` и `Date.after()` но как им можно задать минимальный интервал в день? Или есть другой путь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [`DateUtils.isToday(long)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#isToday(long)).